# Finding the probability that first book is a physics book

Tags: probability

I'm kind of confused regarding this probability problem.

If you have 6 math books and 2 physics books. If we pick 2 books, what's the probability that the first book is a physics book

I tried solving it in 2 ways, not sure which one is correct.

1- Number of ways = 2(ways for choosing physics book) * 6 (ways for choosing math book)= 2*6 = 12
2- Naming physics books as P1, P2, finding the number of ways of each book being the first: =( 1(for P1) * 7(math books + P2)) + (1 (for P2) * 7 (math books + P1)) = 2 * 7 = 14

Which one is correct for the context of the question? Does the context means that first is physics and rest are math, or first is physics and rest are math + the remaining physics book?

Comment: When you calculate a probability, you have to divide the number of favorable outcomes by the total number of possible outcomes.  If you want to make your sample space all ordered selections of two books, then the favorable cases include those with a physics book in the first position and any remaining book in the second position.  That said, the second book is irrelevant given the current wording of the question.

Comment: So you say that the second way is correct?
Like, if we do in tree-diagram (Elements in a set), we'd get smth like this:
(P1, M1), (P1,M2)..(P1,M6), (P1,P2), (P2,P1), (P2,M1)...(P2,M6)
number of elements where P1 or P2 are first is 14, right?

Comment: There are indeed $14$ favorable cases.  However, you have to divide by the $8 \cdot 7 = 56$ ways of selecting two books without replacement to find the probability that the first of the two books selected is a physics book.  That said, you can get the same probability more easily by dividing the two ways you could select a physics book first by the eight ways you could select a book.

Comment: Exactly. So 6(math books) * 2 (physics book) make no sense at all right?

Comment: As I said, you counted the favorable cases correctly in your second method.  Your first method is incorrect.

Comment: I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both considerations are wrong. You have 8 ways to choose a book. It is exactly one of the 8 described books. Provided that you correctly have given the context of question.

Comment: My bad, added the forgotten part. (2 books are picked without replacement)

Comment: @passepartout This does not change anything. In the problem (as it stated) ihe second book plays no role.

Comment: How so? we could choose physics-physics or physics-math (ofc you gotta take into consideration the number of each). i think if it's 8 ways then it's the number of ways of choosing one book.

Comment: @passepartout No matter which book is the second one, it cannot change the book which was chosen first. This is absolutely clear, is not it?

Comment: Hmm kind of confused.. Could you list the ways in which 2 books could be chosen as ordered pairs? (Book1, Book2) ? Maybe I'll get what you mean

Comment: @passepartout As already was said it is absolutely irrelevevant but if you insist... There are altogether $\frac{8!}{6!}=56$ ordered pairs of books. From them $7+7=14$ have a physics book as first. So that the probability to have the physics book as first is $\frac{14}{56}=\color{red}{\frac28}$ as was obvious from the very beginning.

Comment: Exactly, this is my second consideration in the question, why'd you say it's wrong?

Comment: @passepartout You counted the $14$ favorable cases.  However, the *probability* that a physics books is selected first is $\frac{14}{56} = \frac{2}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$, so both of your attempts for calculating the probability were wrong.

Comment: @passepartout I have answered your question before you have edited the latter. There were no words about picking up two books. But also after you inserted the statement I have decided to left the answer unchanged. It demonstrates the origin of the correct answer: whichever book is taken second, third, etc., it by no way influences the probability of a certain book to be taken first. Moreover the same concerns not only the first book but also the second, third, etc. This is the basic fact about independent probabilistic events which one should keep in mind.

Comment: I see. I should make my questions more detailed. Pardon, and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @passepartout You're welcome!